# php report undefined index when used select * in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem only if I use select * but if I select exact field from my database it is working fine

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product id`;";
$resutl = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo $row["product name"];
};
```

It is working if I use

```
SELECT `product name` FROM `product id`
```

Thank you

Comment: Use `var_dump($row);` to see what you actually get. And column names that include white space are not really a good idea, you should think about changing that.

Comment: What does ist say when you use `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { var_dump($row); }`?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product id`;"; remove that semi colon..
$resutl - spelling mistake.

These are not the solution you have saerched for. But it's not a good practice to make mistakes here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product id`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  print_r($row);
}
```

and check your array and traverse it perfectly as when you call all rows it will not be same as fetching one row.

Try this it should work fine, and you will get more idea.
only 2 errors I found is $result variable was not correct and semicolon in query!

Comment: Thank you, after use print_r($row), I found my array field 'product name' is the the capital later 'Product Name'. So, echo $row['Product Name'] is working. This is a good lesson. So never use white space and capital letter for my field again.

Comment: What's wrong with a semicolon in the query? `A command normally consists of an SQL statement followed by a semicolon.` -[dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Table names e column names that include white-space are not a good idea because may be in conflict with mysql sintax (when mysql parse the query). You can use var_dump($row).

Answer (score 0):

Use  **mysql_fetch_array()** instead of **mysql_fetch_assoc()**

While the two are similar mysql_fetch_assoc() only returns an associative array.

Also you should think of moving from mysql to mysqli or PDO. mysql is being removed as of PHP6 and already depreciated as of PHP5.5.